# How to modify a filepath in Python code so that it works on other computers?

Tags: python

I am writing a simple code that runs a batch file and opening of an excel sheet to store some data. I have given the location of the file on my computer. I want to use "pyinstaller" to create an executable so that I can run in other computers as well. Where should I put the *.xlsx and *.bat file in the new computer so that it works, and also should I change the file path in my program? If so how?

```
filepath = r"F:\project\printingdatabase.xlsx"
wb = load_workbook(filepath)

subprocess.call(r"F:\project\batfile\tester.bat")
```

Comment: You can get the location of wherever the .py file is located using `os.path.abspath(__file__)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
# This gets you the dir of the current script in an os-independent way, for example
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))) 

# This appends a subdir "sub-dir" to the base path, in an os-independent way
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'sub-dir')
```